# Bazaar + X = SDLC. What's X? What Issue tracker to choose?

Tags: dvcs, bazaar, issue-tracking

I liked the overview of the Bazaar DVCS but what's the recommended issue tracker to use?
I hope Jira+FishEye will work but it looks like there's no explicit evidence of it.
Would you please point me out to the proper solution.
Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) for hosted solutions. For hosting it privately you can look at [Fusionforge](http://fusionforge.org/).